# Possible to update a commit in Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

Let's say I just commited my file, in Mercurial, with a description such as "removed all the no-longer-needed comments". Some minutes after, I realise that I've forgot to remove some comments of that kind. I'd like to be able to update that commit I did some minutes ago instead of having to do a new one.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you haven't pushed and haven't done any more commits, you can just use `hg rollback`.

Answer (score 2):

The MQ extension enables you to do that. But keep in mind that technically, this creates a new changeset and removes the existing one, so if you have already pushed your previous changeset to an "official"/shared repository, you're out of luck.

I routinely do exactly what you describe here like this:

```
$ hg qimport -r tip  
$ hg qrefresh -e # edit commit message  
$ hg qfinish -a
```

Comment: You should add a warning that you need to do this before pushing this commit elsewhere. If you do that, and edit the commit, you're in for a heap of trouble.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't "get" the mq extension?  Honestly I've tried.  Any good tutorials for it that aren't 5 pages long?

Comment: @Kyle: The "problem" with MQ is that it turns some basic hg concepts/practices around, esp. immutable changeset and DAG. It took me a few days to "get" it, but it's invaluable once you do. I think the best/quickest way is to understand how exactly it works, which is actually very simple: just **a list of patch files** that can be turned into changesets. (To be continued due to comment length limit...)

Comment: @Kyle: (cont.) Read [the section](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html#sec:mq:patch) on patch file, and [another one](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-queues-reference.html#id446370) on series and status files, and see `hg help` on `qnew`, `qrefresh`, `qpush`, `qpop`, then you can do 90% of the things any 5-page tutorial would teach you.

Comment: @Geoffrey - Thanks.  The fact that it messes with the existing DAG was never quite apparent to me from the docs I've read.  After realizing that, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @Kyle: I wouldn't say that MQ "messes with" history. It just changes the otherwise immutable history :) One important "rule" with MQ is do not push patches (`hg push` aborts with patch unless you use -f). Either use `qfinish`, or `qcommit` then push the patch changesets.

Answer (score 2):

The [histedit](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) extension lets you do this.

Like with MQ, you shouldn't edit it if you've pushed elsewhere, but if you haven't, you can do `hg histedit REV` which will list all the changesets between that rev and now, and you select which you want to change. Then, histedit backs you up to the earliest ones, and when you've made your changes, you run `hg histedit --continue`. Wash, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score -1):

If you're sharing your repository, save everyone some headaches and don't try to do this.

Comment: Then that's fine.  I'd go with using the repository explorer in TortoiseHg.  Go to the revision in question, right-click and select `Mercurial Queues > Import Revision to MQ`.  Make your changes, refresh the patch in the Commit dialog, then finish the patch into a new commit.  Haven't done this myself but it should work.  You'll probably need to do the import prior to your updates, or use shelve to temporarily move them out of the way.